# How / Can You Access Google+ Sign-In SessionState with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

To start, I'm new to the whole Google+ API and to Web Development in general, so please excuse me if I'm asking something stupid.

Once you've gotten your user to login with the [Google+ Signin API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button), I know you can use Javascript to check if they're in after navigating to a new page with something like:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
<script>
    function onLoadCallback(){
        var sessionParams = {
            'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID_WOULD_GO_HERE',
            'session_state': null
        };
        gapi.auth.checkSessionState(sessionParams, function(stateMatched){
            if(stateMatched){
                //Nope
            } else{
                //Yep
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, I need to be able to check who they are against a MySQL database via PHP. I could pass the Access Token to a page via PHP POST, but I've been led to believe that isn't precisely secure. Is there any way, and if so, how do I access the PHP equivalent of gapi.auth.checkSessionState() in PHP?

If it's not possible, is there another way to access the user's Access Token in a secure and relatively easy to implement manner? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can set AccessToken value in session so that you can access it via PHP on server.